# There is a way to patch AMD catalyst 14.12 in order to make it work with kernel 4.0.1?

Tags: drivers, kernel, ati, patch

here I go: my OS is Ubuntu 14.04. I was wondering about upgrading the kernel to the recent and latest stable 4.0.1 version (my current one is 3.16). Since I have already installed AMD Omega drivers (14.501.1003/ 14.12), I did remember that those drivers can be patched unofficially, so I patched the menctioned driver following this instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/aginor/4f232d4c28aef7685282). So, based on that patch, it is possible to do some changes on AMD driver and make it compatible with latest kernel 4.0 in a safe way?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use kernel 4.0.1?

Comment: Not really, but maybe there is other people with the same problem about wanting latest stable kernel and AMD drivers fitting together.

Comment: @zx_k9, Did worked to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had problems with catalyst drivers when I upgraded to 15.04 (3.19.0-16-generic)

I suggest you remove the drivers using `sudo apt-get purge fglrx`, reboot and reinstall the drivers available on repository using `sudo apt-get install fglrx` or `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`

more information, please check on this wiki:

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Confirmed, I've also had a problem with 'fglrx', after installing 'fglrx-updates' and choose it as default in Proprietary Drivers window everything works good!